# Nokogiri collects each line as one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I run an affiliate website, and I have code that consumes the XML datafeeds. I have written a method that can scrape and store the data from the XML feed, it works perfectly for say 60 feeds we have. Each row in the feed is created as a @product.

Now enter Linkshare, the code I have that works for the other 60 feeds doesn't work for Linkshare feeds. Instead of having @products.count = a few hundred, it tries to load ALL products into ONE instance of @products, so I get:

> Soul Cal Deluxe Heart Camisole Top - WomensOnly Vest Top - WomensSoul
>   Cal Deluxe Racer Back Vest Top - WomensSoul Cal Deluxe Racer Back Vest
>   Top - WomensSoul Cal Deluxe Racer Back Vest Top - WomensSoul Cal
>   Deluxe Racer Back Vest Top - WomensCrafted Grunge Jumper - WomensMiso
>   Pearl & Fireball Ring Stack - WomensSoul Cal Deluxe Checked Shacket -
>   MensSoul Cal Deluxe Hines Stripe Shirt - MensMiso Embellished Waist
>   Dress - WomensGlamorous Belted Dress - WomensMiso Front Tie Shorts -
>   WomensMiso Tie Front Shorts - WomensSoul Cal Deluxe Stretch Skinny
>   Trousers - WomensSoul Cal Deluxe Stretch Skinny Trousers - WomensSoul
>   Cal Deluxe Stretch Skinny Trousers - WomensVero Moda Bernice Dress -
>   WomensMiso Dipped Hem Maxi Dress - WomensSoul Cal Deluxe Belted Chinos
>   - WomensSoul Cal Deluxe Stretch Skinny Trousers - WomensMiso Jewel Bodycon Dress - WomensMiso Evening Bandeau Dress - WomensMiso Aztec
>   Tube Skirt - WomensCrafted Embellished Neck Dress - WomensMiso Spot
>   Dress - WomensMiso Spot Dress - Womens"}]

(Note, I took just the end of the console log, but you see what I mean.

I've run lots of testing, this has been a problem we've had for a while.

Has anyone had anything like this?

Could it be doctypes or hpricot?

Any Suggestions?

Example feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><merchandiser xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="merchandiser.xsd">
<header><merchantId>36503</merchantId><merchantName>Republic</merchantName><createdOn>2012-01-12/20:21:17</createdOn></header><product product_id="73794" name="Soul Cal Deluxe Borg DLX Zip Through Hoody - Mens" sku_number="73794" manufacturer_name="Soul Cal Deluxe" part_number="73794"><category><primary>Men &gt; Sweats &amp; Hoodies</primary><secondary></secondary></category><URL><product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;offerid=215450.73794&amp;type=15&amp;murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.republic.co.uk%2Finvt%2F73794</product><productImage>http://www.republic.co.uk/content/ebiz/republic/invt/73794/73794_lg1.jpg</productImage><buy></buy></URL><description><short>Blue, Hoodies, Hand wash only</short><long></long></description><discount currency="GBP"><amount></amount><type>amount</type></discount><price currency="GBP"><sale begin_date="" end_date="">34.99</sale><retail>34.99</retail></price><brand>Soul Cal Deluxe</brand><shipping><cost currency="GBP"><amount>3.95</amount><currency>GBP</currency></cost><information></information><availability></availability></shipping><keywords></keywords><upc></upc><m1></m1><pixel>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;bids=215450.73794&amp;type=15&amp;subid=0</pixel></product>
<product product_id="51118" name="Jack &amp; Jones Dale Jack Jeans - Mens" sku_number="51118" manufacturer_name="Jack&amp;Jones" part_number="51118"><category><primary>Men &gt; Jeans</primary><secondary></secondary></category><URL><product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;offerid=215450.51118&amp;type=15&amp;murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.republic.co.uk%2Finvt%2F51118</product><productImage>http://www.republic.co.uk/content/ebiz/republic/invt/51118/51118_lg1.jpg</productImage><buy></buy></URL><description><short>Blue, Straight</short><long></long></description><discount currency="GBP"><amount></amount><type>amount</type></discount><price currency="GBP"><sale begin_date="" end_date="">40.00</sale><retail>64.99</retail></price><brand>Jack&amp;Jones</brand><shipping><cost currency="GBP"><amount>3.95</amount><currency>GBP</currency></cost><information></information><availability></availability></shipping><keywords></keywords><upc></upc><m1></m1><pixel>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;bids=215450.51118&amp;type=15&amp;subid=0</pixel></product>
<product product_id="51128" name="Diesel Straight Leg Larkee Jeans - Mens" sku_number="51128" manufacturer_name="Diesel" part_number="51128"><category><primary>Men &gt; Jeans</primary><secondary></secondary></category><URL><product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;offerid=215450.51128&amp;type=15&amp;murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.republic.co.uk%2Finvt%2F51128</product><productImage>http://www.republic.co.uk/content/ebiz/republic/invt/51128/51128_lg1.jpg</productImage><buy></buy></URL><description><short>Blue, Straight</short><long></long></description><discount currency="GBP"><amount></amount><type>amount</type></discount><price currency="GBP"><sale begin_date="" end_date="">120.00</sale><retail>120.00</retail></price><brand>Diesel</brand><shipping><cost currency="GBP"><amount>0.00</amount><currency>GBP</currency></cost><information></information><availability></availability></shipping><keywords></keywords><upc></upc><m1></m1><pixel>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;bids=215450.51128&amp;type=15&amp;subid=0</pixel></product>
<product product_id="68226" name="Miso Fox Scarf - Womens" sku_number="68226" manufacturer_name="Miso" part_number="68226"><category><primary>Women &gt; Accessories</primary><secondary></secondary></category><URL><product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;offerid=215450.68226&amp;type=15&amp;murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.republic.co.uk%2Finvt%2F68226</product><productImage>http://www.republic.co.uk/content/ebiz/republic/invt/68226/68226_lg1.jpg</productImage><buy></buy></URL><description><short>Stone, Scarves, Machine washable</short><long></long></description><discount currency="GBP"><amount></amount><type>amount</type></discount><price currency="GBP"><sale begin_date="" end_date="">5.00</sale><retail>19.99</retail></price><brand>Miso</brand><shipping><cost currency="GBP"><amount>3.95</amount><currency>GBP</currency></cost><information></information><availability></availability></shipping><keywords></keywords><upc></upc><m1></m1><pixel>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;bids=215450.68226&amp;type=15&amp;subid=0</pixel></product>
<product product_id="67968" name="Levis Pleat Trucker Jacket - Womens" sku_number="67968" manufacturer_name="Levis" part_number="67968"><category><primary>Women &gt; Coats &amp; Jackets</primary><secondary></secondary></category><URL><product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;offerid=215450.67968&amp;type=15&amp;murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.republic.co.uk%2Finvt%2F67968</product><productImage>http://www.republic.co.uk/content/ebiz/republic/invt/67968/67968_lg1.jpg</productImage><buy></buy></URL><description><short>Blue, Jackets</short><long></long></description><discount currency="GBP"><amount></amount><type>amount</type></discount><price currency="GBP"><sale begin_date="" end_date="">30.00</sale><retail>84.99</retail></price><brand>Levis</brand><shipping><cost currency="GBP"><amount>3.95</amount><currency>GBP</currency></cost><information></information><availability></availability></shipping><keywords></keywords><upc></upc><m1></m1><pixel>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;bids=215450.67968&amp;type=15&amp;subid=0</pixel></product>
<product product_id="81217" name="G-Star Dean Army Tapered Jeans - Womens" sku_number="81217" manufacturer_name="G-Star" part_number="81217"><category><primary>Women &gt; Jeans</primary><secondary></secondary></category><URL><product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;offerid=215450.81217&amp;type=15&amp;murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.republic.co.uk%2Finvt%2F81217</product><productImage>http://www.republic.co.uk/content/ebiz/republic/invt/81217/81217_lg1.jpg</productImage><buy></buy></URL><description><short>Black, Straight</short><long></long></description><discount currency="GBP"><amount></amount><type>amount</type></discount><price currency="GBP"><sale begin_date="" end_date="">115.00</sale><retail>115.00</retail></price><brand>G-Star</brand><shipping><cost currency="GBP"><amount>0.00</amount><currency>GBP</currency></cost><information></information><availability></availability></shipping><keywords></keywords><upc></upc><m1></m1><pixel>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;bids=215450.81217&amp;type=15&amp;subid=0</pixel></product>
<product product_id="58377" name="Police 883 Embro Hat - Mens" sku_number="58377" manufacturer_name="Police 883" part_number="58377"><category><primary>Men &gt; Accessories</primary><secondary></secondary></category><URL><product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;offerid=215450.58377&amp;type=15&amp;murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.republic.co.uk%2Finvt%2F58377</product><productImage>http://www.republic.co.uk/content/ebiz/republic/invt/58377/58377_lg1.jpg</productImage><buy></buy></URL><description><short>Black, Hats &amp; Beanies</short><long></long></description><discount currency="GBP"><amount></amount><type>amount</type></discount><price currency="GBP"><sale begin_date="" end_date="">17.99</sale><retail>17.99</retail></price><brand>Police 883</brand><shipping><cost currency="GBP"><amount>3.95</amount><currency>GBP</currency></cost><information></information><availability></availability></shipping><keywords></keywords><upc></upc><m1></m1><pixel>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;bids=215450.58377&amp;type=15&amp;subid=0</pixel></product>
<product product_id="58306" name="Diesel Kyle Beanie - Mens" sku_number="58306" manufacturer_name="Diesel" part_number="58306"><category><primary>Men &gt; Accessories</primary><secondary></secondary></category><URL><product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;offerid=215450.58306&amp;type=15&amp;murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.republic.co.uk%2Finvt%2F58306</product><productImage>http://www.republic.co.uk/content/ebiz/republic/invt/58306/58306_lg1.jpg</productImage><buy></buy></URL><description><short>Black, Hats &amp; Beanies</short><long></long></description><discount currency="GBP"><amount></amount><type>amount</type></discount><price currency="GBP"><sale begin_date="" end_date="">19.99</sale><retail>19.99</retail></price><brand>Diesel</brand><shipping><cost currency="GBP"><amount>3.95</amount><currency>GBP</currency></cost><information></information><availability></availability></shipping><keywords></keywords><upc></upc><m1></m1><pixel>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;bids=215450.58306&amp;type=15&amp;subid=0</pixel></product>
<product product_id="86865" name="Miso Fair Isle Cardigan - Womens" sku_number="86865" manufacturer_name="Miso" part_number="86865"><category><primary>Women &gt; Knitwear</primary><secondary></secondary></category><URL><product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;offerid=215450.86865&amp;type=15&amp;murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.republic.co.uk%2Finvt%2F86865</product><productImage>http://www.republic.co.uk/content/ebiz/republic/invt/86865/86865_lg1.jpg</productImage><buy></buy></URL><description><short>Stone, Cardigans, Hand wash only</short><long></long></description><discount currency="GBP"><amount></amount><type>amount</type></discount><price currency="GBP"><sale begin_date="" end_date="">49.99</sale><retail>49.99</retail></price><brand>Miso</brand><shipping><cost currency="GBP"><amount>3.95</amount><currency>GBP</currency></cost><information></information><availability></availability></shipping><keywords></keywords><upc></upc><m1></m1><pixel>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;bids=215450.86865&amp;type=15&amp;subid=0</pixel></product>
<product product_id="52947" name="White Label Chinos - Mens" sku_number="52947" manufacturer_name="White Label" part_number="52947"><category><primary>Men &gt; trs</primary><secondary></secondary></category><URL><product>http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;offerid=215450.52947&amp;type=15&amp;murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.republic.co.uk%2Finvt%2F52947</product><productImage>http://www.republic.co.uk/content/ebiz/republic/invt/52947/52947_lg1.jpg</productImage><buy></buy></URL><description><short>Stone, Chinos, Machine washable</short><long></long></description><discount currency="GBP"><amount></amount><type>amount</type></discount><price currency="GBP"><sale begin_date="" end_date="">20.00</sale><retail>20.00</retail></price><brand>White Label</brand><shipping><cost currency="GBP"><amount>3.95</amount><currency>GBP</currency></cost><information></information><availability></availability></shipping><keywords></keywords><upc></upc><m1></m1><pixel>http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=g*0hRDNOv4M&amp;bids=215450.52947&amp;type=15&amp;subid=0</pixel></product>
```

Comment: Please post an example of the input.

Comment: Hi jdl - what specifically, what I've posted above is all I have in my console, I have essentially a longer version of that... I'm trying to pull out these values: [{"price"=>"", "brand"=>"", "guid"=>"", "title"=>"", "merchant_link"=>"", "description"=>"", "link"=>"", "image"=>""}]

Comment: Specifically the XML that you're trying to parse.

Comment: We appreciate that you added the sample input, but can you trim it down to the bare minimum needed to illustrate the problem you're seeing? Also, I don't see any sample code showing how you're trying to parse the feeds. We need to see that to be able to help you.

Comment: @theTinMan that is about 1% of the total file, it has been significantly trimmed. Will add the code when I'm back on my laptop.

Comment: Okay, if I read this correctly... You are using Nokogiri to parse the given XML and rather than producing an array of product options, you are getting a single string (or so it seems from the output you included above the sample XML). Can you please go back, restructure your question, start with the input, provide the code you are using to process (including any config for the parser), then the output. If possible show as sample of output in the correct format.

Comment: We need to see the code creating the output. Saying "I have some code that works sometimes, but not others" and then not providing the code gives us no opportunity to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that the XML is malformed. The `<merchandiser>` tag is not terminated. Nokogiri will tell you as much if you check the `errors` method after parsing the document:

```
doc.errors
[
    [0] #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError:0x10109b918
        attr_reader :code = 77,
        attr_reader :column = 1,
        attr_reader :domain = 1,
        attr_reader :file = nil,
        attr_reader :int1 = 1,
        attr_reader :level = 3,
        attr_reader :line = 12,
        attr_reader :str1 = "merchandiser",
        attr_reader :str2 = nil,
        attr_reader :str3 = nil
    >
]
```

Adding a closing `</merchandiser>` tag at the end of the file cleared that up:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('./test.xml'))
#<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x1009ae038
    @node_cache = [],
    attr_accessor :errors = [],
    attr_reader :decorators = nil
>
```

After fixing that I parsed for `product`:

```
doc.search('product').size
 => 20
```

There are `<product>` collisions:

```
<product>
  <URL>
    <product />
  </URL>
</product>
```

which could confuse your code. It confused my search above that reported 20 occurrences.